# Search function not really searching

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7

I have the following code which is suppose to search for the letter 'e' within a string, return `False` if 'e' was found within the string and return `True` is the 'e' was not found :

```
def has_no_e(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter == 'e':
            return False
        return True
```

As per my understanding, the `for` loop will access the characters within `word`one by one and check them against the condition i've set, which is `if letter == 'e'`

Each time i run the program, it seems the for loop is only checking the first letter for some reason!

so calling the function with `has_no_e('dde','e')` will result return `True`. but if i switch it around `has_no_e('edd','e')` it will return `False`

I'm running Python 2.7.3 on a x86 Windows 7 Ultimate machine... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return True
```

is inside the body of the for loop so it will execute straight away after it checks if the first letter is `'e'` (unless the first letter is `e` then it will return `False`).

Comment: That's ok but see the answer by @DanielRoseman It's best not to re-invent the wheel :D

Answer (score 7):

Others have pointed out your error, but the whole function is overly complicated. You can just do this:

```
def has_no_e(word):
    return 'e' not in word
```

Comment: niiiice. it'll take me some time to develop that kind of programming mentality. i'm still very new to python and programming in general. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

your `return` is indented wrong. unindent it (to the same level as `for`), and it'll work

Comment: Thanks. indenting return was the answer! it's amazing how dumb one can be while learning :P